# Writing my nextPage() function as a global function so that it can be accessed by the onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My objective is to make all animations work by triggering seperate elements instead of just using the "randomizer" or "Dl menu list".**

First of all here the JSFiddle. I left it unchanged and identical to the original (except that the multi level menu doesnt show up, no idea why: http://jsfiddle.net/EbhdM/3/

This is the original demo http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/

Im trying to solve this since a month, reading javascript articles and experimenting with things.

I intend to use cases in my nextPage() function, So I removed the on click function in the HTML and wrote this:

```
<button type="button" data-animation="1" class="btn">PAGE 1</button>
```

This allows me to write as many buttons as I want as long as I have the class="btn"

The I bound the on click event to the buttons which have the btn class, to trigger my animations in the nextPage() function

```
$(".btn").on('click', function (event) {
    var dataAnimation = $(this).attr('data-animation');
    nextPage(dataAnimation);
});
```

the value in my data-animation will be my "case" number in the nextPage() function. Case number means the animation number. There are 67 animations.

So far I managed to bind it to the animations using buttons but I cant get it to animate. Im really a starter when it comes to javascript but I tried my best. I dont know the solutions and I would be very happy if you could help me solve this, also explaining me what I did wrong.

Here the JsFiddle of what im talking about http://jsfiddle.net/7rGkd/1/

I assume this will work if I would write my nextPage() function as a global function so that it can be accessed by the onclick event, but how? How do I write this?

Comment: It doesn't need to be global, it just has to be in the same or an ancestor scope of the click handler function. You haven't put it into the jsfiddle at all, so it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong (other than trying to call a nonexistent function).

Comment: Handler functions only need to be global if you reference them from the `onclick` attribute of an HTML element. If you call them from Javascript code, normal scope rules are followed.

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle you haven't defined your nextPage() function...

That said, try this?

```
nextPage = function(arg) {
    //your code
}
```

by not adding the `var` keyword, you're making it global